# Django forms not working (the button is doing nothing)

Tags: python, django, forms

I am new to Django and after I created two forms (TopicForm and EntryForm) only the second one is not working.
When I click the button Add Entry, nothing happens.
I can't see where the issue actually is, pretty strange because I did almost the same thing for the first form and eveything is good.Tell if I need to share any other files.
There is no textarea for the new entry, just that button.

forms.py:

```
from django import forms

from .models import Topic, Entry

class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ['text']
        labels = {'text': ''}

class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = ['text']
        labels = {'text': 'Entry:'}
        widgets = {'text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80})}
```

urls.py:

```
"""Defines URL patterns for learning_logs."""

from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'learning_logs'
urlpatterns = [
    # Home page
    path('',views.index, name='index'),
    # Page that shows all topics.
    path('topics/', views.topics, name='topics'),
    # Detail page for a single topic.
    path('topics/<int:topic_id>/', views.topic, name='topic'),
    # Page for adding a new topic
    path('new_topic/', views.new_topic, name='new_topic'),
    # Page for adding a new entry
    path('new_entry/<int:topic_id>/', views.new_entry, name='new_entry'),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from .models import Topic

from .forms import TopicForm, EntryForm

def index(request):
    """The home page for Learning Log."""
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/index.html')

def topics(request):
    """Show all topics."""
    topics = Topic.objects.order_by('date_added')
    context = {'topics': topics}
    return render(request,'learning_logs/topics.html',context)

def topic(request, topic_id):
    """Show a single topic and all its entries."""
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
    context = {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topic.html', context)

def new_topic(request):
    """Add a new topic."""
    if request.method !='POST':
        # No data submitted; create a black form.
        form = TopicForm()
    else:
        # Post data submitted; process data.
        form = TopicForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('learning_logs:topics')

    # Display a blank or invalid form
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request,'learning_logs/new_topic.html',context)

def new_entry(request,topic_id):
    """Add a new entry for a particular topic."""
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)

    if request.method !='POST':
        # No data submitted; create a blank form.
        form = EntryForm()
    else:
        # POST data submitted; process data.
        form = EntryForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_entry = form.save(commit=False)
            new_entry.topic = topic
            new_entry.save()
            return redirect('learning_logs:topic',topic_id=topic_id)

    # Display a blank or invalid form.
    context = {'topic': topic, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/new_entry.html', context)
```

new_entry.html:

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <p><a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic.id %}">{{ topic }}</a></p>

    <p>Add a new entry:</p>
    <form action="{% url 'learning_logs:new_entry' topic.id %}" method='post'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ forms.as_p }}
        <button name='submit'>Add entry</button>
    </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Topic(models.Model):
    """A topic the user is learning about."""
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        return self.text

class Entry(models.Model):
    """Something specific learned about a topic."""
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'entries'

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        if len(self.text) > 50:
            return f"{self.text[:50]}..."
        else:
            return f"{self.text}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `forgot` to set `type="submit"` in your `button`. Add `type="submit"` then try.

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<p><a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic.id %}">{{ topic }}</a></p>

<p>Add a new entry:</p>
<form action="{% url 'learning_logs:new_entry' topic.id %}" method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" name='submit'>Add entry</button>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Same thing, also there is no text area to type something, it s just the button.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add models.py also?

Comment: of course......

Comment: Change `{{ forms.as_p }}` to `{{form.as_p }}`